# react-native android genymotion error java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, genymotion

I am using genymotion 2.6.0, android api23,react-native.

I have created the project using cmd  **react-native run-android**

and for js server, I have used the  **npm start**

The project is created and I m trying to run the project on genymotion..

[it shows the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSDCR.png)

[if I tried to reload the error change to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t5F7.png)

I have tried adb reverse TCP:8081 TCP:8081

Also dev setting /debug/ debugserver host&port for device

Here I have written my IPAddress i.e **192.168.30.2:8081**

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem .i was using the custom phone - 6.0.0 -API 23 -1768x1280
actullay it was giving some openGL  render error(i checked from adb logcat)..further i check it was about GPU
Then i download an other emulator google Nexus 5 -6.0.0 -API 23 - 1080x1920 
it just solve the problem.. :)